# Getting specific content from TinyMCE editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, tinymce, shortcode

I have a plugin im building for wordpress that injects a shortcode with content inside it after the user selects options for that plugin. What im having trouble with is `tinyMCE.get('content').getContent()` this is called when a user wants to update those options but using this pulls **everything** thats in tinymce, I need it limited to the content inside the shortcode open and close tags. For example: after a user selects options of the plugin, a shortcode of `[plugin]---HTML OPTIONS---[/plugin]` will be created but when `tinyMCE.get('content').getContent()` is called I need it to grab everything inside of said plugin tags and nothing else like so: `[plugin]---GET THIS CODE----[/plugin]` any help would be grateful. Let me know if you need clarification on anything.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are attempting then what you are looking for is the 
tinymce.dom.Selection class [(doc)](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4:class.tinymce.dom.Selection)

More specifically:

```
// Sets some contents to the current selection in the editor
tinymce.activeEditor.selection.setContent('Some contents');

// Gets the current selection
alert(tinymce.activeEditor.selection.getContent());
```

You might take a look at code in some of the available plugins. The *link* plugin in particular works with text selections.

Comment: Thanks DFriend for your reply, but I think either my code is wrong or the selection is not what im looking for. When I add this code into mine, it actually injects whatever I put in setContent(). So if I put `tinymce.activeEditor.selection.setContent('[fullwidth]Test[/fullwidth]');` then the editor now has that code, which is not what I want, becuase its already there. I need it to grab that code '[fullwidth]Test[/fullwidth]' and return it elsewhere. Does that make sense?

Comment: @ZacNespral21, yes, that makes sense. To grab a selection use `selection.getContent()`.
The Selection class has numerous methods to determine the current node (element) and for setting the selection range around the element.